# Is there a "best" way to edit CSS?

Tags: css

Is there a "best" way to edit CSS?

I'm looking for a designer tool. It has to "visual"... less code.
Visual studio does a good job but it seems to be lacking when it comes to the actual design stage.

Comment: If you're looking for a visual "non-code" editor, is it really a programming question any more?

Comment: No, there is no "best" way. There are lots of good ways, though. What you're really asking is, "What's the best CSS editor", which is subjective. Recommend making this a community wiki before it gets closed as subjective. Separately: The community at http://doctype.com (a StackExchange-based site, like SO) might be more able to pitch in (although in reference to nickf, I think CSS is a form of programming but don't wish to get into a big debate about it :-) ).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

My suggestion is [CSSEdit by MacRabbit](http://macrabbit.com/cssedit/).  It's focused on just editing CSS, and is very visual without hiding code.  You can edit CSS attributes through a GUI, or directly edit the text in the code.  You  can preview your work on any site, even applying your edited CSS to the display of live Web sites.  As a plus or minus depending upon your platform of preference, it's a Mac only application.

Comment: I was just going to say that!  CSSEdit is absolutely awesome, now I wish we had a version on Windows for my day-job.

Comment: Yes. No windows version is a no go. I've checked it out... they seem to have a very good designer centric approach.

Answer (score 3):

Here's what I do:

1. Design the page semantically, using lists, headings, paragraphs etc.
2. Add classes and ids where appropriate.
3. Open the unstyled page in Firefox.
4. Open Firebug.
5. Write/edit the CSS there and see the results instantly.

Comment: Can you work directly with the CSS files in Firebug? Like, can you save your changes and such? I mean... one accidental refresh or something like that and your new styles are gone... :p

Comment: CSS files are not modified when you work in Firebug. So your original styles are always safe. :)

Comment: @Aseem yeah, that's exactly his problem I think :)

Comment: @Svish: it's not too hard to just copy and paste your changes periodically.

Comment: @nickf: ctrl+s is even easier. And copy-pasting might be messed up. I have for example several times hit ctrl+v when I meant ctrl+c...

Comment: There's another magic button there which is ctrl+z, you know. In any case, I've been using the above method for years and it's been great.